# An error occurred while launching Anypoint studio

Tags: windows, mulesoft, launch, anypoint-studio

I am trying to launch Anypoint studio 7.15 version. But I get a pop up saying an error occurred and to check the .log file created in the workspace.

However .log file does not have any information other than below.

```
!SESSION !SESSION !SESSION
```

I have tried uninstalling. It's tricky to understand what's the issue without any error stack trace in .log file .

Could someone quickly suggest.

Thanks in advance !

Also , I have checked the jdk paths in my env variables. All looks fine.
I am using jdk11.

Comment: There is no error message in the question.

Comment: Edit your question to add the contents of the file AnypointStudio.ini, the output of `java -version` from the command line and the values of JDK paths and environment variables you checked.

Comment: Also your operating system and architecture. and a screen shot of the error if you can not copy its text.